# Can't modify hugepage size once DPDK application is stopped

Tags: linux, memory, dpdk

I am running a DPDK application and for that i allocate huge pages using a script. Allocation and starting the application is fine. But later when I stop the application and release the hugepages by deleting the mount point and modifying below nr_hugepages for a numa system.

Later when I try to allocate further hugepages it doesn't seem to be working.

How I release hugepages :

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages

echo 0 > sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages

 echo "Unmounting /mnt/huge and removing directory"
 grep -s '/mnt/huge' /proc/mounts > /dev/null
 if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
     sudo umount /mnt/huge
 fi

 if [ -d /mnt/huge ] ; then
     sudo rm -R /mnt/huge
 fi
```

Then later when I try to write any new value to the nr_hugepages but it is not taking any value. It is stuck with previous value

```
# echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
# echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
#
# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
2048
# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
2048
# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node0/meminfo | fgrep Huge
Node 0 AnonHugePages:     10240 kB
Node 0 HugePages_Total:  2048
Node 0 HugePages_Free:   1024
Node 0 HugePages_Surp:      0
# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node1/meminfo | fgrep Huge
Node 1 AnonHugePages:    145408 kB
Node 1 HugePages_Total:  2048
Node 1 HugePages_Free:   1024
Node 1 HugePages_Surp:   2048

# cat /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
2048
# echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
# cat /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
0
# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node0/meminfo | fgrep Huge
Node 0 AnonHugePages:     10240 kB
Node 0 HugePages_Total:  2048
Node 0 HugePages_Free:   1024
Node 0 HugePages_Surp:   2048

# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node1/meminfo | fgrep Huge
Node 1 AnonHugePages:    145408 kB
Node 1 HugePages_Total:  2048
Node 1 HugePages_Free:   1024
Node 1 HugePages_Surp:   2048
# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
2048
# cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
4096
```

If anyone has faced this issue earlier and what did you do to get rid of this ? Any pointer or workaround will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove huge page mmapping files after process exit. Search`/dev/hugepages` or `/mnt/huge` or any other place mounted as hugetlbfs for file with  `rte_` prefix. Each file in these locations is consuming at least one hugepage.